# Dynamics AX pdf files generation through batch

Tags: batch-file, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I generate pdf files based on reports through a server batch job(using runbasebatch class and reportRun class), if i don't schedule job just executing the class, it works perfectly, I have readable pdf files, if scheduled, my pdf files are corrupted, they all have a size of 1 ko.In this case, I have no error on batch history.
any ideas?
thanks in advance

using AX 2009 no SP1, acrobat reader 7 on AOS
Already remove any image logo

Comment: I can't tell if this is a programming question or not. Try adding some source code (otherwise this probably belongs on [su]).

Comment: Does your class execute well on server side ?

Comment: Any errors in the batch log?

Comment: Which version of AX? Some versions of AX had problems generating images to the PDF file when run in batch.

Comment: using AX 2009 no SP1, acrobat reader 7 on AOS, execute well on server side if not scheduled, no error in batch log

Answer (score 2):

If there are images in the report, the problem resides in the fact that the [Image class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa636710%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) can only run on client.

You can fix images in batch report by using the System.Drawing.Image class.
Read the full details on how to change the code in a blog post of a colleague of mine who fixed this already for us.

[Kevinroos.be Dynamics AX Printing logo's from batch](http://www.kevinroos.be/2011/01/dynamics-ax-printing-logos-from-batch/)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing any images in the report.

The is an error in image batch printing in AX 2009 before certain CU.